# Is there a way to clear all local storage but save cookies in macOS Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, local-storage

I know from the `chrome://settings/siteData?search=cookie` page that I can see "all cookies and site data", trash individual items, or "remove all".

And I know I can open Chrome DevTools for any window, visit the Application tab, and clear all storage for any one particular site.

But is there a means to remove only local storage for all sites, without trashing all cookies?

I'm open to extensions and console scripts. I've found extensions for deleting cookies from sites I don't whitelist, but I've yet to find such an extension that also deletes local storage.

Answer (score 1):

Found a extension for that:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod

As shown on the screenshot, there is a separate localStorage deletion option:

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Clear Cache**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn

Can do this too:

[image: screenshot]